# How to make Qt QMainWindow to be in focus and overlay when clicked with the mouse when there is window overlay

Tags: c++, windows, qt

i have Qmainwindow that opens with show() method another QMainWindow 
the problem is that when the second QMainwindow is on top the first one , when i click with 
the mouse on the  first QMainWindow it doesn't return to be on top of the second windows.
its getting the focus  but doesn't go on top ..   so its looks funny and not natural windowing behavior.

update ..
im using 2 QMainWindows . i know its not standard but i need the toolbar+ status bar of the 
window via the Designer.
any way in the 2 QMainWindows i don't have any properties set , i suspect this is where the solution .
the code is simple in the main window i have member of another QMainWindow 
and in the main window i just do :

```
....  
ListWindow* m_pListWindow; // the second qmainwindow
......
void MainWindow::actionViewlistHandler()
{

    m_pListWindow->show();

}
```

Comment: Do you have minimal code sample to reproduce the problem? Also what version of Qt you're using

Comment: Having two QMainWindows for a single app is a bit strange too

Comment: @Mat why is that? If you want to have two separate windows with status bar and menubar it is a good shortcut to go with.

Comment: the answer is to make the other window with no parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you give the 2nd MainWindow the first one as its parent

```
//This will cause the problem
MainWindow2 *m2 = new MainWindow2(this);
m2->show();

//This will solve your problem
MainWindow2 *m2 = new MainWindow2();
m2->show();
```